# Facebook Page Tab fails to load in rails 4.0

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.0 to develop facebook page_tab. I got blank content showed on the facebook tabpage.
From what I think, the issue is related to turbolink. The following are the firefox requrest and response headers

Response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2013 08:54:54 GMT
Status: 200 OK
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
X-XHR-Current-Location: /page_tab
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Etag: "5d34060006e527f1a21db545df3d919f"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie:  _likenotlike_session=SEhKbk5oZ0FHT2o0RkRMK3k2OThidHY1Yk5HYjdIWGNkNFIrWisxbkVKRitLT2tJM2d2b1NVV0xQYW5Qc015L0ljVjdDWCtITWR4cUhLc2VjK3hGUHNCbHAzb0YxV1F4OUNaa0hudDE0MkFZRlhYUGgxK2M5eDBNMTRIZzdhZXVyRTBmZEx3Q1RKaXRrZFJwaUYyY2JMdUNpSmlZRmhNS0Z6dGFEMEE5b2RLOXJGdWF0Z1NHcDR1N0ZleVgvZDRJLS1KcjhndzRuUjJaSXZnd1lNdjUyNTJBPT0%3D--a51e845979d81ace643d14b399ffa655ece63d79; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: aac0e275-92b7-4b4b-9be7-b811ff9dec29
X-Runtime: 0.024202
```

Request Header

```
POST /page_tab HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=5
Cookie: fbm_353759128067702=base_domain=.localhost; fbm_470420673030979=base_domain=.localhost; request_method=POST;   _likenotlike_session=T2o2dVZUSkhxUDhWdDJyWGsvQmYxZHVGVGszYy9pc2VIdGs3OWJ0YkRQTSt2eTJtR2pxTDZLSFRpbWVDamx2ZFVxU2pJRENNRzl2elNqMkF4Q01hcTlWZkZNNUVnSy9ucnJrUWQ0YWFheUJqRklsaEQ1RlM5ZGN1MEhGV0NpQ0E5bjc0VXZoQThuVzJjbjFQTmpZeUVzK2M1anRBamZqU3VwZVlYUlNpQmRnYnlVNWJZTk5wc3dZTEZpR0lyWTE2LS1tSkRHb3JpNGM4U205bEdxMEpkOE5nPT0%3D--85ea3314a43d08dda9d00218a5045968ef040d0b
Connection: keep-alive
```

In the response header there are X-*-* headers that I think are related to ajax. So I think rails together with turbolink think that the request is the ajax request but actually the request is normal post request if you can see from the request header above.

Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the problem is the following link
http://conpanna.net/en-us/blog/5185b5ce79ec73ae54000003

Just add response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "GOFORIT"
and every thing works